# How to have multiple file size restrictions when using rich:fileUpload

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

When using `rich:fileUpload`, we define the max file size limit on web.xml by defining the context parameter `org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize`.

The problem is that this component is used on several parts of my system, and the requirements define different restrictions on the max file size upload, i.e., in on place the max size is 300Kb and in other it is 700Kb, for example. The worst case is that a single page has 2 different upload components, each one with different limitations.

Since size is defined as a context parameter, I cannot change it programmatically. Is there a workaround for this situation?

I'm using richfaces 4.2.2.Final, jboss 6.1.0.Final.

Comment: You can check file size in file upload listener. This listener works with UploadedFile object. You need react on length of uploadedFile.getData() in your listener(s).

Comment: Hi @VasilLukach, I suppose listener will fire only after upload completes, right? If so, there is a way to check file size before upload (for better user experience)?

Comment: No, listener starts before uploadcomplete. Easy check with debug and alert in fileUpload: `onuploadcomplete="alert('load complete');"`